# Core Animation with custom view

Tags: core-animation, core-graphics

I got a view subclass with the following `drawRect:` method:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {

    [myBackgroundImage drawInRect:rect];

    ... // more, complex drawing such as strings, lines, etc.
}
```

I want to animate a background image transition to another background image, while the rest of the view drawn above the background image *remains the same*. How would I do that? Will I need an additional `CALayer`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you might use multiple layers: one for each background and another for the rest in the foreground. So that you can apply animations and transformations on each layer separately. This is a solution that I have been succesfully using in Flex with Sprites: organized a display list using separated graphical objects layered one above another and moving/rotating/fading and whatever applied to any of them.

As a design principle it should work in all graphical environments including iOS.

The one thing to take into account: transformations applied on the superlayer of the children layers affect all sublayers at once.